# Populate table in twig with for loop

Tags: twig

I want to populate my table in twig with a for loop and some if statement.

```
{% for user in users %}
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 1 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 2 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 3 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 4 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
      <td>
      {% if user.planningday == 5 %}
          {{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
{% endfor %}
```

But that's not working and i dont know why. 
Example :
 I try to populate my planning with 2 user. The first user select the day 5 so friday, the second user select the day 1 so monday. In my planning, first user have his name displaying on the friday , the second one is displaying after the friday  and not on the monday . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you loop all the user, thus creating a calendar for all the users. If you want to group the users into one table try this aproach

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    {% set assigned_user = '' %}
    {% for user in users if user.planningday == i %}
        {% set assigned_user = user %}
    {% endfor %}
    <td>{{user.name}} {{user.lastname}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/1gc6w4)